# restricting hist_verify in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history, history-expansion

Is it possible to bypass `hist_verify` for specific history commands? For instance, I rarely have the need to verify `!$` or `!!`, whereas I find verification to be a useful feature for more complicated history expansions. Can select history operators be excluded from history verification?

Comment: What if there's both a `!!` and `!rm`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
accept-line() {
  if [[ ${BUFFER//![\$!]} = *!* ]]; then
    set -o histverify
  else
    set +o histverify
  fi
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N accept-line
```

added to your `~/.zshrc` as a heuristic. That is, redefine the `accept-line` widget (invoked when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) so that it sets the `histverify` option only if there's a `!` followed by a character other than `!` and `$` in the current line.

That's fooled for command lines like `echo '!e' !!` or `\!!rm` but it seems it should be an acceptable limitation.

Personally, I add `set +o banghist` to my `~/.zshrc` and prefer relying on `history-search-backward` (bound on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> by default in `emacs` mode) or `history-beginning-search-backward` (which I bind on <kbd>PageUp</kbd>) which saves some typing and always gives me a visual feedback before I accept the command.

Comment: I agree the limitations are quite minor and unlikely to arise during normal use. The main reasons I use the two history expansions that I mentioned are for encapsulating the previous line in a substitution (e.g., `<(!!)` or `$(!!)`) or re-using the last argument of the last line (which in bash can also be done by Alt+. or Esc+.). Not sure if there are better alternatives for these patterns.

Comment: @user001, Alt+. works in `zsh` as well (in emacs mode). For `<(!!)`, you can always recall the command you want (Up, ^R, Alt+p...), then ^U to erase and `<(^Y)`

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea (`^U` / `^Y`). I must have disabled Alt+. by setting `vi` mode.